# How can i convert the date to aplhabetical readable format in java

Tags: java

I have a program in which i will get date in the below format "2015-01-17"

Please tell me how can i convert this data to this format JAN 17 2015 .

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;


public class TestDate {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String s1 = "2015-01-17 ";

        System.out.println("Result==> "+sdf1.format(sdf2.parse(s1)));
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to look into a bit more at SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: Aren't both `2015-01-17` and `JAN 17 2015` *readable*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your `sdf2` to use the `MMM dd yyyy` format instead...

```
String text = "2015-01-17";
try {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy");

    Date date = sdf1.parse(text);

    System.out.println("Result==> " + sdf2.format(date));
} catch (ParseException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

Which outputs...

```
Result==> Jan 17 2015
```

Comment: If you display the month like this, You should also provide a locale to the SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle Wouldn't that depend on the context in which it is being used?  If run locally on the client machine, then the default local should be fine.  (I take your point, but I'm lacking context to say one way or another)

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String dateInString = "2015-01-17";

try {

    Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
    System.out.println(date);
    System.out.println(formatter.format(date));

} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I am getting this below exception , java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2015-01-17"
 at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
 at TestDate.main(TestDate.java:16)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) documentation, you should be able to do that by parsing a date as follows: `MMM dd yyyy`.

Comment: Nit Pick, the OP is parsing with `yyyy-MM-dd` and "formating" with `MMM dd yyyy` ;)